# Hazelcast cluster_members unexpected argument

Tags: python, hazelcast

I trying run hazelcast in Python. I got an error on `hazelcast.HazelcastClient( cluster_members =[ "127.0.0.1:5701"])`

> Error : TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cluster_members'

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new way of configuration for the 4.x version of the client. If you are using Hazelcast IMDG 4.0 or newer, make sure that you install the 4.0 version of the client with the following command.

```
pip install hazelcast-python-client==4.0.0b1
```

We only released the BETA version for the time being, the final release should be available in near time.

If you are using Hazelcast IMDG 3.x, you can take a look at the old examples using [3.12.z](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client/tree/3.12.z) branch.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()
config.network_config.addresses.append("ip-adress(i.e. 127.0.0.1:5701)")
client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)
```